# Using Roaster, how can I generate an interface with a specific generic type (or types)?

Tags: java, roaster

I'm currently using [Roaster](https://github.com/forge/roaster) to generate interfaces, but my interface has generic types bound to it.

Here's what I was trying to generate them to begin with:

```
String entityName = "SimpleEntity";

JavaInterfaceSource repository = Roaster.create(JavaInterfaceSource.class)
        .setName(entityName + "Repository");

JavaInterfaceSource jpaInterface = repository.addInterface(JpaRepository.class);
jpaInterface.addTypeVariable(entityName);
jpaInterface.addTypeVariable("String");
```

But the above results in generated code that looks (something) like this:

```
public interface SimpleEntityRepository<SimpleEntity>
        extends
            org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository {
}
```

What I actually want is for the generic to be bound to `JpaRepository`.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JavaInterfaceSource#addInterface`](http://javadox.com/org.jboss.forge.roaster/roaster-api/2.18.1.Final/org/jboss/forge/roaster/model/source/InterfaceCapableSource.html#addInterface-java.lang.String-)  is overloaded with a `String` signature.  This means that you can create a generic type by doing some clever string concatenation.  It also returns the same instance of `JavaInterfaceSource`, such that in the above example, `jpaInterface == repository`, so that operation is both unnecessary and misleading.

Since it's overloaded with `String`, we simply add the generics (read: angle brackets) we want ourselves.

```
repository.addInterface(JpaRepository.class.getSimpleName() +
                                    "<" + entityName + ", String>");
```

It may not be as type-elegant as the rest of the API, but it generates the right object in the end.

```
public interface SimpleEntityRepository
        extends JpaRepository<SimpleEntity, String> {
}
```

Comment: Makoto, as for your bounty, looking into the code it looks like the best easily available solution. The only other route is to use `addInterface(JavaInterface<?> type)` method but [`JavaInterface`](http://javadox.com/org.jboss.forge.roaster/roaster-api/2.18.1.Final/org/jboss/forge/roaster/model/JavaInterface.html) doesn't support specifying substitutions for generic parameters either: it is not supported by [`TypeVariableSource`](http://javadox.com/org.jboss.forge.roaster/roaster-api/2.18.1.Final/org/jboss/forge/roaster/model/source/TypeVariableSource.html).